# Multiple upload with Dropzone and inividual input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Created a form which upload multiple files without problems. Trying now to in corporate input fields to each file before uploaded.
I've followed an example from Dropzone which does this without a `<form>`. Now i struggle to pass the `<input>` field along with the image to the upload-url.

Below is a snippet of my code.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-block fileinput-button"><span class="fa fa-ticket"></span> Add cards</span>
    <span class="fileupload-process">
        <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-small active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="files" id="previews">
    <div id="template" class="file-row">
        <div class="file-cell">
            <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
            <div class="progress progress-small active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="file-cell">
            <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
            <button class="start"><span>Start</span></button>
            <button data-dz-remove class="cancel"><span>Cancel</span></button>
            <button data-dz-remove class="delete"><span>Clear</span></button>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control cardInput cardName" placeholder="Card name" name="cardName" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var previewNode = document.querySelector( '#template' );
previewNode.id = '';
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild( previewNode );

var myDropzone = new Dropzone( document.body, {
    url: 'scripts/cardnew.php',
    thumbnailWidth: 150,
    thumbnailHeight: 204,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: false,
    previewsContainer: '#previews',
    clickable: '.fileinput-button',
    addRemoveLinks: false
} );

myDropzone.on( 'addedfile', function( file ) {
    file.previewElement.querySelector( '.start' ).onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile( file ); };
} );
myDropzone.on( 'totaluploadprogress', function( progress ) {
    document.querySelector( '#total-progress .progress-bar' ).style.width = progress + '%';
} );
myDropzone.on( 'sending', function( file ) {
    document.querySelector( '#total-progress' ).style.opacity = '1';
    file.previewElement.querySelector( '.start' ).setAttribute( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
} );
myDropzone.on( 'queuecomplete', function( progress ) {
    document.querySelector( '#total-progress' ).style.opacity = '0';
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dropzone.js's website suggests](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending) that you can submit any data in addition to the file by registering for the `sending` event and using a callback function with three parameters: `file`, `xhr`, and `formData`. Inside this callback function, you may then append additional custom fields to the `formData` to be submitted as POST data along with the file. Note that this implementation will require you to use an HTML `<form>`.

In your case, since you're trying to send a separate `input` field with each image when a button is clicked, you can achieve this by appending a new `input` field to the file container `div` on your page each time the `addfile` event is triggered, assigning each `input` field an `id` of `myinput_<filename>`, where `<filename>` is the name of the file with which the newly-appended `input` field is associated. Then, when the user clicks the button to upload all of the files at once, you can insert into the callback function for your `sending` listener a line to add the associated file's `input` field value into the `formData` like this:

```
formData.append("somefield", document.getElementById("myinput_" + file.name));
```

Since the [Dropzone.js documentation for `sending`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending) says that the event is triggered before each file is sent, then each file will be processed individually in this way.

Ultimately, your solution could have a snippet that looks something like this:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    document.getElementById("#file_container_div").innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="myinput_' + file.name + '" value="">';
    // Your other code goes here...
});

myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("somefield", document.getElementById("myinput_" + file.name));
    // Your other code goes here...
});
```

Of course, the solution you ultimately choose to implement will need to be customized a bit to fit your needs, but this should be enough to express the concept.

Comment: Where should the <form> be added? To each individual preview/file?

Comment: There should be one `form` block and it should surround any `input` fields that you'd like submitted with the file uploads. For example, simply placing the line `<form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone"></form>` in your code will create an area for files to be dropped. I should amend the part of my answer where I say to append the `input` fields to a `div` in your code, and instead recommend that you append them to a `div` in the `previewTemplate`. That way, the `input` fields should be within the `form` block because they have been appended to the `previewTemplate`.

Comment: Added <form> and <input> inside the form, i managed to send data along with the image. I did not succeed in adding multiple <input> along with multiple images upload.